# Getting error while fetching record from table using CodeIginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting the following error while fetching record from table using CodeIgniter.

Error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function result() on a non-object
<p>Severity: Error</p>
<p>Message:  Call to a member function result() on a non-object</p>
```

I am providing my code below:

```
$this->db->select('pt_tours.tour_id,pt_tours.tour_title,pt_tours.tour_location,pt_tours.tour_days,pt_tours.tour_nights,pt_tours_departure_dates.tour_id,pt_tours_departure_dates.dep_dates');
    $this->db->join('pt_tours_departure_dates', 'pt_tours.tour_id = pt_tours_departure_dates.tour_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('CONCAT(","','pt_tours_departure_dates.dep_dates','",") like "%,"$date",%"');
 $res = $this->db->get('pt_tours')->result();
echo $this->db->last_query();exit;
```

Here I am trying to get record by matching the date value with column which contains the comma separated string value.

Comment: Could you explain string inside Where condition?

Comment: Satya, some advice. Most of your questions carry a tone of begging and pleading, which may put some readers off answering. You may find [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) of some use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may replace result() with result_array()